# algorithm2e get rid of newline after then

Tags: algorithm2e

I'm having this code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
                \If{cond}{
                        stmt1\;
                }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me this:
[image]

This makes some algorithms much shorter, I'm searching for a way to get rid of the newline after the `then` (for `ifs` where the body is only a oneliner). Is this possible with `algorithm2e` and if yes how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a one line if-statement you can use `\lIf` (line if). The semicolon is added automatically.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
                \If{cond}{
                        stmt1\;
                }
                \lIf{cond}{
                        stmt2
                }
                other things
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See page 32 of the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) for the different macros for if-then-else constructs.

Comment: Thanks, should then the `then line text` also not end with `\;` ? (with it there is an empty newline after the `then` is this normal?)

Comment: I think `\;` is only needed to separate the lines of a multi-line block, so it is not needed in a single-line if-statement. Maybe (but that's just speculation, I didn't check it) a `\;` is interpreted as a line ending, whereas a single-line if-statement has an automatic line ending already, resulting in two consecutive line endings and therefore an empty line.

Comment: Ok, thank you ;)